# Image borders getting pixelated (Mobile page in android app)

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

if I browse my site with my smartphone or iPod, my joystick looks like this:
[1 http://images.devs-on.net/Image/4Qi0Imug2x7gyY6S-Bereich.png](http://images.devs-on.net/Image/4Qi0Imug2x7gyY6S-Bereich.png)

If I load this site into my app everything looks fine until I start dragging the stick (jQuery draggable). Then it looks like this:

If I don't drag it looks fine but as soon as I start dragging it's looking like this:
[2 http://images.devs-on.net/Image/NZYoP7Vcs04mqn55-Bereich.png](http://images.devs-on.net/Image/NZYoP7Vcs04mqn55-Bereich.png)

If I visit my site with my mobile browser no problem. Only if the site is within my app.

The stick is an image (img tag) while the outer image is an background-image from another division.

ANY ideas what could cause this?

/edit
I found out that this happens if I tap ANYWHERE on my screen.

Comment: Make sure the actual image size matches the size that it is being displayed at in the img tag.

Comment: JQuery draggable, is likely changing some part of the CSS that is causing the jaggies to appear. After the drag try ~refreshing the DOM objects. IMG.src=''; IMG.src=src; DIV.backgroundImage=''; DIV.backgroundImage=bgsrc;

Comment: But can it be that this only happens if I load my site into my android app? If I browse it with my mobile browser everything looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a resizing issue. look into ways of using graphics in Android apps safely ;)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html

Best of luck.